# How to characterize the maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x]$ and $\mathbb C[x]$ ?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It is known that if $M$ is a maximal ideal of $C[0,1]$ then for some $r \in [0,1]$ , $M=\{f  \in [0,1] : f(r)=0\}$ , can we also characterize the maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x]$ ? I think I somewhere read that there is a bijective correspondence   between the maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x]$ and points on the upper half plane but am not able to prove it . And what about maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x]$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*For $\mathbb C[x]:$* First note that it's a PID, so every ideal is generated by a single polynomial. Also $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed. So every non-constant polynomial splits into linear factors. Hence the maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x]$ are of the form $\langle x-a\rangle,$ for some $a \in \mathbb C.$ In other words the maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x]$ are in one-one correspondence with the points of complex plane.

*For $\mathbb R[x]:$* The maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x]$ corresponds to the irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb R.$ So the only possible choices are the linear factors and the irreducible polynomials of degree 2.

*Added:* Choose a degree two irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbb R$ and factorize it over $\mathbb C.$ Then we will have $f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})$ and at most one of the $\alpha, \bar{\alpha}$ will be in the upper half plane. Similarly, choose an element $\alpha$ in the upper half plane which is not real. Then $f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})$ will be a degree two irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb R.$ The linear polynomials corresponds to the point in the real line. This will give you the required correspondence between upper half plane and maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x].$

Comment: I've been unable to prove that "there is a bijective correspondence between the maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x]$ and points on the upper half plane." May be others will answer this question.

Comment: but then how will you answer the fact that the example written above will be a maximal ideal in $\mathbb R[x]$

Comment: @learnmore: I didn't understand your question. Sorry. Will you be more explicit?

Comment: yes sure  I am asking any 4 degree polynomial may be irreducible in $\mathbb R$ so why will not we include them

Comment: @learnmore: There is no irreducible polynomial of degree $4$ over $\mathbb R.$ To see this, factor the polynomial over $\mathbb C$ and it will look like $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})(x-\beta)(x-\bar{\beta}).$ Now $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})$ and $(x-\beta)(x-\bar{\beta})$ are two real polynomials, giving a factorization over $\mathbb R.$

Comment: yes thanks my problem is solved now +1 for your effort